# UITableViewCell size does not follow Content View size

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I have two UITableViewControllers which use the same set of cell templates, therefore I have created a table view controller in my Storyboard which contains these templates. My table view controllers instantiate an instance of this template holder tableview, then in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` they deque one of it's cells, and configure it as they need.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *widgetDict = [self.widgets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DMSWidget *widget = [self.widgetStorageTableViewController.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Key Value Row"];

    ...

    return widget;
}
```

These cells have their inner layouts set up entirely using AutoLayout.

Everything works fine, except that I get cells which have the standard 44 px height and width of the table view, with Content Views narrower than this (depending which they contain, the ones with less contents are smaller), and are longer than the cells themselves. So the Content Views overlap the next cell but don't fill the entire width.

I don't understand, how this could happen. How is it possible, that the `UITableViewCell` has different size than it's Content View? They should be the same, isn't it?

What I tried to do but failed:

- implement `-tableView:heightForRowatIndexPath:`: tried to return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, but did not help
- reload my table view when the sizes are calculated: does nothing
- add hacks to cell implementations, like setting `autoresizingMask` in `-awakeFromNib`: I could make the Content View expand to the width of the cell itself, but it was still overlapping to the next cell

*UPDATE:* It looks like it is not related to the dual table view architecture. When I copy my cell to the tableView where it will show up, has the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: it was all my fault. In some of the ancestors of my cell has an init, which called `-initWithFrame:` explicitly with `CGRectZero`. After removing this, iOS 8 could use it's frame values and everything worked fine.